# Only need ID token in oidc

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid

I was using oidc middleware with the following config:

```
oidcConfig = {
     issuer: configObj.oktaIssuer,
      client_id: global.configuration.oktaClientId,
      client_secret: global.configuration.oktaClientSecret,
      appBaseUrl: configObj.appBaseUrl,
      scope: 'openid profile',
      response_type: 'code',
      loginRedirectUri: configObj.appBaseUrl+'/authorization-code/callback',
      routes: {
        callback: { defaultRedirect: '/' },
        login: {
            path: '/signin',
         },
        loginCallback: {
            afterCallback: '/application/dashboard'
        }
    }
};
```

On successful authentication a cookie is created with both access token and id token and locale information.

I only need ID token for my application during logout and don't need access token and locale information

I was able to remove locale information by removing profile as scope, but still nothing found to remove access token. Any leads will be appreciated.

```
nodeApp.use(
cookieSession({
    httpOnly: true,
    name: 'sample',
    keys: ['xxx', 'xxxx'],
    signed: true,
    // Cookie Options
    maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 8 hours
})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In use cases where a web backend gets its data directly from a database and does not call APIs you can use a flow that only returns an ID token. After validating the ID token, the app creates its own cookie based session.

To do so, configure `response_type=id_token` rather than `response_type=code`.